# How to automatically create nuget packages on every build (using TFS 2013 Build)?

Tags: nuget

We are trying to automate the "nuget package creation" process as part of our daily build process (using TFS 2013 Build).

Package creation goal:

- We have three projects (creating a total of three output assemblies)
- We want to wrap each assembly into it's own nuget package, and create one other nuget package that contains all three assemblies

We are using an out-of-the-box TFS build definition template (for scheduled builds). I can't seem to find any built-in support for doing any kind of nuget packaging in there. I can write a custom powershell script and plug it into the build process as a post-build-script. But wondering if there is a better (re-usable/out-of-the-box) way to automate the nuget package creation. Any suggestions on things I should go look at?

Comment: I can't see anything [online](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/), looks like you will have to make one.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://nugetter.codeplex.com/ this will do what you are looking for. I used this as a starting point for my customised template